# redirect page using GET method

Tags: javascript, php, security

I have to redirect page using GET method and I don't want to show GET query string parameters in the URL. For security reasons I cannot allow end user to modify my GET parameters. Also, I can't use POST method here because on the page on which I am redirecting is accepting only GET parameters. 
I have SSL already setup on this page.

```
https://www.ddd.com?url=secureURL.com
```

Hacker can change it to

```
https://www.ddd.com?url=www.google.com
```

I have tested locally so far is

```
<form method="GET" name="sub" action="SELF">
    <input type="hidden" name="parameter1" value="1234" />
    <input type="password" name="parameter2" value="werwer2" />
    <input type="text" name="parameter3" value="werwer3" />
</form>

<script language='javascript'>
    document.sub.submit();
</script>

<?php
$buildURL = "http://localhost:8080/mypage?parameter1=1234&parameter2=werwer";
header("location:$buildURL ");
?>
```

How can I achieve this? Htacces? OR any other method???

Comment: use `header("Location: ...")` for that: http://php.net/manual/bg/function.header.php

Comment: Use `openssl_decrypt()` method It will surely help you.

Comment: you could calculate a hash, include a salt, and then perform a redirect while validating if the GET is authorized to execute, if so continue with the redirect by sending a header Location, just a free thought

Comment: @RuchishParikh I dont have access to decrypt on other side

Comment: @niklon I cant share SESSION or anything with the third party service

Comment: @mitkosoft header still shows parameters in URL, Hacker can change this on the fly!!

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND, you are missing the point. If your business logic is in your PHP script and you just do `header("Location...")` to desired website based on it, nothing will be exposed as GET parameters.

Comment: @mitkosoft Even if after applying Header location, I can see full redirect URL in URL bar for 2-3 seconds.

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND, better show us what you have tried so far, otherwhise the discussion will become endless.

Comment: @mitkosoft check updated question javascript redirect and php redirects

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND, do you have control over redirected page (the page which can receives only GET)?

Comment: @mitkosoft That's the biggest issue! I dont have control over that redirected page code.

Comment: I don't see any option then. If you cannot negotiate with the "receiver" how to change standard GET approach, you simply cannot do anything.

Comment: @mitkosoft Thanks! I will have to find another solution on this!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent tampering of a URL parameter, you can use an HMAC

http://rc3.org/2011/12/02/using-hmac-to-authenticate-web-service-requests/

Otherwise, you should use white-listing of URLs on your server